# Blurred polygon feature, OpenLayers

Tags: angular, openlayers, polygon, blur

Is it possible to get blurred color fill of polygon? Can't find anything in the web about this problem. Even official documentation has nothing about this.

Comment: What do you mean by "blurred" color? setting opacity?

Comment: I mean color. I want it to look like heat map.